# systemd kill my processes before ExecStop completed

Tags: linux, systemd

I'm trying to update my application to use it with systemd.
When I have used Upstart, I've just create a */etc/init.d/myService* script:

```
#!/bin/bash
#chkconfig: 2345 90 10
#description: myDescription

### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides: myService
# Required-Start: sshd
# Required-Stop: sshd
# Default-Start: 2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop: 0 1 6
# Short-Description: start myService
# Description:
### END INIT INFO

SCRIPT=$(readlink -f $0)
lockfile="/var/lock/subsys/myService"

do_start() {
    if [ -d "/var/lock/subsys" ]; then
        touch $lockfile
    fi
    ...
}

do_stop() {
    ...
    if [ -d "/var/lock/subsys" ]; then
        if [ -f "$lockfile" ]; then
            rm -f $lockfile
        fi
    fi
}

do_status() {
    ...
}


case "$1" in
  start)
    do_start
    exit 0
    ;;
  stop)
    do_stop
    exit 0
    ;;
  status)
    do_status
    exit 0
    ;;
  restart)
    do_stop
    do_start
    exit 0
    ;;
  *)
    echo "Usage: $SCRIPTNAME {start|stop|status|restart}" >&2
    exit 3
    ;;
esac
```

And all were fine.

**Notice**, this script generate some subprocesses which will executing in background.
To use it with systemd, I made the follow service file (*myService.service*):

```
[Unit]
Description=My Description
Requires=sshd.service
After=sshd.service
Before=shutdown.target reboot.target halt.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/etc/init.d/myService start
ExecStop=/etc/init.d/myService stop
RemainAfterExit=yes
KillMode=none

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

If I run

```
systemctl stop myService.service
```

All work fine. My application stop successfully by */etc/init.d/myService stop* command.

But I've got the follow issue:
When I reboot the system, and */etc/init.d/myService stop* is executing, process which I should stop by *myService* script already killed. There are many processes which I should control ( around 7 processes ), and system should not terminated it itself.

I've tried to use Type=forking and specify the PIDFile as a pidfile of process, which has the longest life-time ( it should started first end stopped last ), however all my process were terminated again.

Is any simple way to avoid killing my subprocess?

If it's matter, application running by another user ( no root ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was found.

I ran hadoop & hbase, some of their components was starting by ssh-connection to localhost, and processes, which was started by this way, was unable to be controlled by systemd.
It was the design for distributed system, but in my case the work is going on the one machine. So I have replaced in *hadoop/bin/slaves.sh*

```
for slave in `cat "$HOSTLIST"|sed  "s/#.*$//;/^$/d"`; do
 ssh $HADOOP_SSH_OPTS $slave $"${@// /\\ }" \
   2>&1 | sed "s/^/$slave: /" &
 if [ "$HADOOP_SLAVE_SLEEP" != "" ]; then
   sleep $HADOOP_SLAVE_SLEEP
 fi
done
```

to

```
for slave in `cat "$HOSTLIST"|sed  "s/#.*$//;/^$/d"`; do
eval "$@"
 if [ "$HADOOP_SLAVE_SLEEP" != "" ]; then
   sleep $HADOOP_SLAVE_SLEEP
 fi
done
```

The problem was resolved and now processes are showing in service process tree.

Hbase probably has the same solution, but now it start with distributed=false and don't start any process by ssh.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same/similar problem. I assume you do su or sudo in the "myService" script?
That causes your services process(es) to start in the user.slice instead of in the system.slice. 
Apparently nothing "important" is supposed to be running in the user.slice and systemd just kills all(?) processes there at shutdown/reboot. 
I solved it by removing all user switches (su/sudo) in my start scripts and using the User directive in the unit file (User=xxx).

Check where (in what slice) your processes run with *systemd-cgls*